# Unlimited Pro Pack in Doodle army mini militia

Tags: android, doodle-army

While playing the online game Doodle army 2 mini militia I have seen users with unlimited life and extra guns/ammo. If anyone has played this game then they might know they have extra guns and bombs from the starting of the game and how useful that is in game.

How do they do that? Is there any kind of cheat or hack I am unaware of?

Doodle army 2 mini militia

Answer (score 1):

Even you could get extra ammo and bombs from the store once you get enough  battle points to buy them. For example.

[image: Buying ammo] 
[image: Buying extra grenade]

If you are talking about infinite health, I don't think so thats possible. The game might be lagging behind so you might be feeling that the person is not dying.